# How to make Jquery focus on only the current HTML "select" and remove only the current "option"

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have this code, and I have it removing my first "option" because the first one says "Please Select:". Anyways, problem is, when I focus on my first "select" it removes the first "option" from EVERY select. How do I make it remove it from ONLY the currently focused one?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select').live('focus',function() {
   $('.firstoption').remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select:first').on('focus',function() {
   $(this).children("option:first").remove();
  });

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ky6zq/2/

This will execute every time the select receives focus, so you will keep removing elements every time.  To prevent this issue try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select:first').one('focus',function() {
   $(this).children("option:first").remove();
  }); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ky6zq/1/

Comment: that's going to be the first select every time, not the current select.

Comment: ah, very nice! I have a class on each first option, but with your code don't need that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('focus', 'select', function() {
       $('.firstoption', this).remove();
   });
});
```

You should be using the delegated version of `on()`, not `live()` which is deprecated.

Make sure you use a class for the first option, so as to not remove an option every time the select receives focus.

Comment: Could `one()` be used to prevent removing an option each time?

Comment: yeah I have ".firstoption" as the class on the first option actually. Wasn't just for demonstration :P Thank you!!

Comment: @kmb385 - Not when binding the event to the document or another non dynamic element like this.